# Vagrant: Machine enters invalid state randomly

Tags: windows, centos, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm getting the following error randomly when issuing 'vagrant up' on my centos box:

> The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
>   to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
>   'unknown' state. Please verify everything is configured
>   properly and try again.
>
> If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
>   it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
>   GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
>   For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
>   VirtualBox GUI is open.
>
> The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
>   is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.

It happens 2 every 3 times (random estimate) and when it runs it works flawlesly. It happens always right after `SSH auth method: private key`. In Virtualbox GUI machine is up, running and prompting for user and password (I can run the GUI and it works fine).

Host OS is Windows 10. This is my Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
VAGRANTFILE_BOX_NAME = "centos-drupal-vm"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # Base config
  config.vm.box = "enemy-of-the-state/centos-7.1_kernel-devel-fixed"
  config.vm.hostname = VAGRANTFILE_BOX_NAME
  config.vbguest.auto_update = true
  config.vm.define VAGRANTFILE_BOX_NAME do |plxbox|
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  end

  # Port forwarding
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.0.0.10"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 80 # httpd
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 443, host: 443 # ssl
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3306, host: 3306 # mysql
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8025, host: 8025 # mailhog

  # Provider settings
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = VAGRANTFILE_BOX_NAME
    v.memory = "2048"
    v.cpus = 1
  end

  # Ansible provisioning (from guest)
  # : From shell
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "ansible/init.sh"
  # : From plugin
  # config.vm.provision :guest_ansible do |guest_ansible|
  #   guest_ansible.playbook = "ansible/playbook.yml"
  #   guest_ansible.sudo = false
  # end

  # Virtualbox synced folder
  config.vm.synced_folder "./html", "/var/www/html", type: "nfs"

  # A private dhcp network is required for NFS to work (on Windows hosts, at least)
  config.vm.network :private_network, type: "dhcp"

  # Reload network config
  config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "echo Everything done: http://10.0.0.10"
end
```

Any clue or any other info that might be useful? Thanks!

EDIT:

Adding `vagrant up` output:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'centos-drupal-vm' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> centos-drupal-vm: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> centos-drupal-vm: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> centos-drupal-vm: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    centos-drupal-vm: Adapter 1: nat
    centos-drupal-vm: Adapter 2: hostonly
    centos-drupal-vm: Adapter 3: hostonly
==> centos-drupal-vm: You are trying to forward to privileged ports (ports <= 1024). Most
==> centos-drupal-vm: operating systems restrict this to only privileged process (typically
==> centos-drupal-vm: processes running as an administrative user). This is a warning in case
==> centos-drupal-vm: the port forwarding doesn't work. If any problems occur, please try a
==> centos-drupal-vm: port higher than 1024.
==> centos-drupal-vm: Forwarding ports...
    centos-drupal-vm: 80 (guest) => 80 (host) (adapter 1)
    centos-drupal-vm: 443 (guest) => 443 (host) (adapter 1)
    centos-drupal-vm: 3306 (guest) => 3306 (host) (adapter 1)
    centos-drupal-vm: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    centos-drupal-vm: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> centos-drupal-vm: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> centos-drupal-vm: Booting VM...
==> centos-drupal-vm: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    centos-drupal-vm: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    centos-drupal-vm: SSH username: vagrant
    centos-drupal-vm: SSH auth method: private key
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'unknown' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

Comment: Are you trying to use your own private key to login? In that case you might have to add `config.ssh.private_key_path` and even pass the public key to the VM and rename it to authorized_keys

Comment: I tried telling vagrant to insert the key and it has the same results: sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. I don't know where it's failing so I can't provide more information. Vagrant tells the machine is in an 'unknown' state and Virtualbox shows that everything is fine.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output that you are getting when running vagrant up? Looking at the output might help analyze the problem more quickly.

Comment: Updated with the 'vagrant up' output. Thanks!

Comment: From what I could see this could be a virtualbox issue rather than vagrant , are you using virtualbox 5.1.16? There have been issues reported in that version. Virtualbox 5.1.14 seems to be a more stable release. If your case matches with the virtualbox version maybe try using virtualbox 5.1.14 and see.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Virtualbox 5.1.16 but this issue was present with previous versions too. I couldn't reproduce it in another environment either so it seems a problem with this particular host machine but I got no clue what could cause it.